# Convert characters of a string to opposite case

Tags: java, string, char, uppercase, lowercase

//HERE WHY IS IT CONVERTING TO LOWER CASE BUT NOT TO UPPER CASE

````
public class LowerUpperCase {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="lowerUppercase";
       
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i++) {

            if(s.charAt(i) >='a' && s.charAt(i)<='z'){  //OR IF DONE THIS NOT WORKING
```
   if((s.charAt(i) >='a' && s.charAt(i)<='z' ) || (s.charAt(i) >='A' && s.charAt(i)<='Z')){
```

               
                 s=s.toLowerCase();//here should i go for 

            }
            else if(s.charAt(i) >='A' && s.charAt(i)<='Z'){
               
                s=s.toUpperCase();

           }
           
            
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
````

//I ALWAYS GET OUTPUT LIKE loweruppercase or LOWERUPPERCASE

```
INPUT:LowerUpperCase
OUTPUT:lOWERuPPERcASE  expected

HERE WHY IS IT CONVERTING TO LOWER CASE BUT NOT TO UPPER CASE 

I ALWAYS GET OUTPUT LIKE loweruppercase or LOWERUPPERCASE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems on the righ track, but you need to toggle between both lower and upper case.  Try this version:

```java
String s = "lowerUppercase";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) >= 'a' && s.charAt(i) <= 'z') {
        output.append(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)));
    }
    else {
        output.append(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i)));
    }
}

System.out.println(output.toString());
// LOWERuPPERCASE
```

Note that the above assumes that you would only have lower and upper case English alphabet letters in the input string.  If not, then the answer might have to change.

Comment: You could add `Character.isLowerCase();` or `Character.isUpperCase();` instead of the rather narrow a/z check.

Answer (score 0):

You now know why. Here is yet another way you could do it:

```
String s = "Lower to UpperCase";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
         sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(c));
    }
    else {
        sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
    }
}
s = sb.toString();
System.out.println(s);
```

This will output to the Console Window:

```
lOWER TO uPPERcASE
```

Comment: Why do you only handle `isAlphabetic`? You may want to target only characters with upper and lower case. But for example `isAlphabetic('〤')` is true, but `isLowerCase('〤')` and `isUpperCase('〤')` are both false. [Character.isAlphabetic()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isAlphabetic(int)) returns true for many characters.

Comment: I prefer no filtering at all or filtering with `isLowerCase(x) ^ isUppcaCase(x)`. `isAlphabetic(x)` is half-baked.

Comment: Uhhhh...Now I see what you're talking about and you are right. Using 'isAlphabetic` or anything else here is rather moot. I removed it altogether. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are calling the method on the entire string while you only wanna switch the case of the char at position i. Your code example sets the entire string to lowercase if the last letter is lowercase and to Uppercase in the other case.

Also String in Java is an immutable object, meaning that you cannot change its value once it's created, so you need a stringBuilder.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "lowerUppercase";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) >= 'a' && s.charAt(i) <= 'z') {
                sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i)));
            } else {
                sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i)));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
```

If you'd like to play with functional programming here's the functional version (It's not practical or anything, purely educational) :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "lowerUppercase";

        StringBuilder out = s.chars()
                .map(i -> {
                    if (Character.isLowerCase(i)) {
                        return Character.toUpperCase(i);
                    } else if (Character.isUpperCase(i)) {
                        return Character.toLowerCase(i);
                    }
                    return i;
                }).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append);

        System.out.println(out);
    }
```